# How should I create secondary DbContext using ContextProvider.EntityConnection?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm using breeze with Code First EF. My production DbContext has IDatabaseInitializer that throws an exception if `!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)`. If I create a context like suggested in [the documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider) database compatibility cannot be checked.

```
// The following line will throw NotSupportedException.
// Unable to verify the compatibility of the model because
// the DbContext instance was not created using Code First patterns.
var context2 = new MyDbContext(EntityConnection, false);    // create a DbContext using the existing connection
```

How should I instantiate DbContexts providing ContextProvider's EntityConnection?

Comment: No, it's not the case. MyDbContext builds the model using Code First. Everything works fine when I create it passing only the connection string or using the default ctr. `var context2 = new MyDbContext();`

Comment: what the section in the DOCU Create your ObjectContext/DbContext Dynamically ?

Comment: @phil-soady Follow the link I provided and scroll down to "ContextProvider methods for use in BeforeSaveEntities and AfterSaveEntities" http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider#ContextProvidermethods .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During `SaveChanges`, Breeze's `EFContextProvider` creates a `DbContext` instance using the default constructor.  This happens prior to `BeforeSaveEntity()` and `BeforeSaveEntities()`.  So you can rely on that first DbContext instance to check compatibility before your second DbContext instance is created.

In your DbContext, set the database initializer only in the default constructor.  In the constructor that takes a `DbConnection`, set the initializer to null:

```
public MyDbContext() : base()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CompatibilityCheckingInitializer<MyDbContext>);
}

public MyDbContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, false)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(null);
}
```

This way, you can re-use the database connection on your second DbContext, but still have the initializer working on your first.

Naturally, you are still free to create DbContexts using any constructor you want, as you would have prior to Breeze 1.4.  Using the `EntityConnection` property in your constructor is suggested as a way to help you conserve database connections.

Comment: This makes sense, to check compatibility on the first DbContext. It's still unclear why the second DbContext thinks it's not Code First?

Comment: I think it's because the EntityConnection (that we pass in the DbContext constructor) already has metadata associated with it, so it doesn't need to build the metadata as it normally would with Code First.  And we can't give it a plain DbConnection because [EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/26/exception-from-dbcontext-api-entityconnection-can-only-be-constructed-with-a-closed-dbconnection.aspx)