# Enable Lazy Loading on AfterSaveEntities using Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm using breeze with EF6 and `EFContextProvider`.
 
On save changes I'm **using** :

```
{ TransactionType = TransactionType.TransactionScope };
```

I'd like to use lazy loading for validating my entities easier during the AfterSaveEntities delegate but I can't do that.
 Trying to set **`LazyLoadingEnabled = false`** during the transaction doesn't work.
 Entities still don't load relations when needed.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to load the entities manually.  In fact, as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301730/working-with-beforesaveentity-and-navigation-properties?answertab=votes#tab-top), you should create a separate EF context for loading any additional entities.

When the SaveResult is sent back to the client, any additional entities that are attached via navigation properties will be serialized along with the original entities.  So you should keep the original context clean unless this is your intent.

Comment: This works. But I think it's using another connection to the database in the same transaction since I'm using TransactionScope on SaveChanges settings. Does this mean my project now uses DTC instead of lightweight transactions? Is there any way to make the new DBcontext enlist to the current transaction?

Comment: What do you mean "validate during AfterSaveEntities"? Why would you validate AFTER you save? And why would you enlist the validation inside the transaction? Finally, why are you changing the default transaction settings ... which come into play only during the actual save, not the before and after activity? You want the boundaries of the transaction to be as small and as brief as possible so that you minimize database pressure and maximize performance.

Comment: You can create your second context using the same connection, as described in the [ContextProvider helper methods](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/contextprovider#ContextProviderMethods) part of the documentation.  [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901261/how-should-i-create-secondary-dbcontext-using-contextprovider-entityconnection/17917284#17917284) provides additional guidance.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe add those two SO answers to Breeze tutorials?